# Unrecognized selector occurring for int property

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties, cocos2d-iphone, unrecognized-selector

I have a class called Projectile (it inherits from the Cocos2D CCSprite Class, but I doubt that's related to the problem).  All it contains is an int called 'type', which I have made into a property.

Projectile.h:

```
@interface Projectile : CCSprite{

int type;

}

@property int type;

@end
```

Projectile.m:

```
#import "Projectile.h"

@implementation Projectile

@synthesize type;

@end
```

Now all I'm trying to do is set that property in the main class of my game, like so:

```
-(BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

Projectile *newProjectile = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"Bullet.png"];

newProjectile.position = spaceShip.position;

newProjectile.type = kLaser;               // defined earlier as #define kLaser 1


[objectsSpriteSheet addChild:newProjectile z:kProjectileZValue];

[projectiles addObject:newProjectile];

return YES;

}
```

Every time I run this, it crashes on the newProjectile.type = kLaser line:

```
-[CCSprite setType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ed82f10
```

It seems almost too simple to get wrong, and Xcode is clearly aware of the property as it autocompletes it and doesn't give me an error to say it doesn't exist.

I've also got very similar code elsewhere which executes perfectly.

If anyone could shed some light on this I would be most grateful, I'm sure I could get round it another way, but I'd like to understand why this doesn't work if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well yes, when you are saying `Projectile *newProjectile = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"Bullet.png"];`, newProjectile will be an object of type CCSprite, which doesn't have that property.

Comment: You are indeed correct, what a stupid mistake! Thank you very much!

Comment: Interesting: not even an Analyze build catches this issue.

Comment: yep ... for anything that is not related to project setup or the organizer , ie for coding :) , i now use another tool. It found sooooo many under-analysed issues, not funny.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg - what tool do you use?

Comment: @Kreiri JetBrain's AppCode. Current EAP version 2.0 really working well for me. It's had its growing pains, but it is really beginning to look like a JetBrains product now. Still insufficient for 'playing with certificates' (imo) and certainly for anything related to the appStore. But for the rest , bang on.

Answer (score 2):

This line causes the issue:

```
Projectile *newProjectile = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"Bullet.png"];
```

Change it to:

```
Projectile *newProjectile = [Projectile spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"Bullet.png"];
```

You are creating the instance of `CCSprite` and assigning it to it's subclass. The `CCSprite` class don't have a property like type.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I've selected Levi's answer as the correct one as he was first.

Comment: @user1606549: with pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but just try this :

```
Projectile *newProjectile = (Projectile *)[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"Bullet.png"];
```